# is it ok to pass the solid instance got from a weakReference to other class instance and stored there?

Tags: kotlin, weak-references

In order to break the circler reference, in one place a solid instance is passed to a class which keeps it within a weak reference.  But this second class also passes the instance de-referenced from the weak reference to other class and that class just stores it as normal reference.

Will the de-referenced instance out from a weak reference block the GC to free that instance?

Or it should be always stored in the weakReaference down the chain?

```
class sample (listner: Listener) {
    var listener: WeakReference<Listener> = WeakReference(listener)
    lateinit var otherClass
    init{
        // now passing the solid listener to other class
        otherClass: OtherClass = OtherClass(getListener())
    }
    fun getListener() {
        return listener.get()
    }
```

the OtherClass stores the instance as normal reference:

```
class OtherClass(var listener: Listener) {
}
```

Comment: `WeakReference.get()` returns strong reference (or null) which will prevent GC. But Java itself doesn't have issues with clearing circular references - have you encountered a memory leak already?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, as long as one of your classes holds a reference to an object, it won't get freed.
Otherwise, your `OtherClass` would experience an unexpected behavior.